# how can I program my sound sensor and pir motion sensor in 1 arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

```
int pirPin=2;
int buzzerPin=12;
int soundSensor = 19;
int LED = 3;
int statusSensor=0;
int pirVal=0;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
pinMode(soundSensor, INPUT);
pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);  
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
pirVal=digitalRead(pirPin);
if(pirVal==HIGH)
{
Serial.println("Motion Detected");
digitalWrite(buzzerPin,HIGH);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
}
else
{
digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
 }
statusSensor = analogRead(soundSensor);

  if (statusSensor == 1)
  {
Serial.println("Sound Detected");
digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}  
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Please align your code (select code, press ctrl-k) and align { and } blocks,  what is currently wrong/not according to your expectations? what do you expect?

Comment: I expected to run both of them at a time

Comment: And what exactly it is not doing now? (we cannot look at the result or expect us to create the circuit you built to check it). How should they interact with each other?

Comment: Is your sound sensor analog or digital?

Comment: @EmanAli, the body of the question should have more than just the code.  It should also explain your problem.  Remember, the goal is to have a collection of questions and answer that everyone can later use.  If you make an effort to create a good question, then everyone with a similar question will benefit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no pin with pin number 19 (as you defined a soundSensor on it), and there is no problem you can use my sound sensor and pir motion sensor in 1 arduino uno.

But in order to do that please use **millis** instead of **delay** so that your arduino doesn't wait to read reading of other sensor during the reading of first sensor.

Here is a link which shows how to use arduino for multitasking..

https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview